# How can I define an enumerator with string values in JDL?

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

It is possible to define an enumerator with values in String in JDL as follows and with result in Java and Angular

JDL may be

```
enum LocaleLanguage {
    ES_ES("es_ES"), ES_CA("es_CA"), EN_GB("en_GB"), EN_US("en_US")
    loacle String
}
```

Java result may be

```
public enum LocaleLanguage
{
    ES_ES("es_ES"),
    ES_CA("es_CA"),
    EN_GB("en_GB"),
    EN_US("en_US");

    private String locale;

    LanguageLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }
}
```

Angular

```
export const enum LocaleLanguage {
    ES_ES = 'es_ES',
    ES_CA = 'es_CA',
    EN_GB = 'en_GB',
    EN_US = 'en_US'
}
```

Comment: I think Swagger has this functionality, but I am not sure if JHipster does too

Comment: @Lino think Jhipster JDL doesn't support it, see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#enumerationdeclaration

Answer (score 0):

At this time this is not possible. A way to circumvent this *issue* would be to use translations and in the front end change the value to the desired String.